# Formula for Christoffel Symbols in Terms of Derivatives of Riemannian Metric with Contravariant Indices?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, relativity

The following formula represents the usual textbook way of computing the Christoffel symbols of the second kind ${\Gamma^i}_{jk}$ via the Riemannian metric with covariant indices $g_{mn}$ and spatial derivatives thereof.

$${\Gamma^\ell}_{ij} = \frac{g^{\ell k}}{2} \left( \partial_i g_{jk} + \partial_j g_{ki} - \partial_k g_{ij} \right) $$

As an exercise for pleasure, I have been trying to see if it possible to derive a formula for the Christoffel Symbols in terms of the Riemannian metric with contravariant indices $g^{mn}$. In my derivation, I have seem to have gotten stuck and am curious if anyone might have any ideas on how to proceed further.

I have begun by trying to expand $\partial_i g^{mn}$ and see where this leads me. Note: $\mathbf n_{id}$ represents a vector normal to the tangent space where the derivative is being taken, so it drops out of the equation quickly.

$$\begin{align}
\partial_i g^{mn} &= \partial_i \left( \mathbf e^m \cdot \mathbf e^n \right) \\
&= \partial_i \mathbf e^m \cdot \mathbf e^n + \mathbf e^m \cdot \partial_i \mathbf e^n \\
&= \partial_i \left( \mathbf e_d g^{md} \right) \cdot \mathbf e^n + \mathbf e^m \cdot \partial_i \left( \mathbf e_d g^{nd} \right) \\
&= \partial_i \mathbf e_d g^{md} \cdot \mathbf e^n + \mathbf e_d \partial_i g^{md} \cdot \mathbf e^n + \mathbf e^m \cdot \partial_i \mathbf e_d g^{nd} + \mathbf e^m \cdot \mathbf e_d \partial_i g^{nd} \\
&= g^{md} \left( {\Gamma^q}_{id} \mathbf e_q + \mathbf n_{id} \right) \cdot \mathbf e^n + \delta_d^n \partial_i g^{md} \left( {\Gamma^q}_{id} \mathbf e_q + \mathbf n_{id} \right) \mathbf e^m + \delta_d^m \partial_i g^{nd} \\
&=2\partial^i g^{mn} + g^{md} {\Gamma^n}_{id} + g^{nd} {\Gamma^m}_{id} \\
&= - g^{md} {\Gamma^n}_{id} - g^{nd} {\Gamma^m}_{id} \\
&= -{{\Gamma^n}_i}^m-{{\Gamma^m}_i}^n
\end{align}$$

Since ${{\Gamma^n}_i}^m \ne {{\Gamma^n}_m}^i$ due to the fact that the two Christoffel symbols transform differently, we cannot attempt to plug in this result $\partial_i g^{mn} = -{{\Gamma^n}_i}^m-{{\Gamma^m}_i}^n$ into an expression like $\partial_i g^{jk} + \partial_j g^{ki} - \partial_k g^{ij}$ and expect term cancellations that will result in us being able to solve for the ${{\Gamma^n}_i}^m$.

Is there anything that can be done beyond this point to generate an expression for the Christoffel symbols in terms of $\partial_i g^{mn}$ or is this futile?

Comment: I believe the covariant index k on the LHS of your first equation should be i instead.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to Math.SE.

Comment: Lewis Miller, you are right. I will edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should try as follows. Since

$$
\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}=g^{\mu\sigma}g_{\sigma\nu}
$$

by taking the derivative of both sides of the equation with respect to e.g. $x^{\tau}$ you find

$$
0=(\partial_{\tau}g^{\mu\sigma})g_{\sigma\nu}+g^{\mu\sigma}(\partial_{\tau}g_{\sigma\nu})
$$

Hence, after multiplying both sides by the metric and rearranging terms, you obtain that

$$
\partial_{\tau}g_{\lambda\nu}=-g_{\lambda\mu}\,g_{\nu\sigma}\,\partial_{\tau}g^{\mu\sigma}
$$

which gives you the derivative of the metric in terms of the derivative of the inverse metric. Now you can plug-in this formula into the definition of $\Gamma$ to obtain what you're looking for.

Comment: That's a very concise way of doing it! Thank you.

After putting it that way, I realized that I could continue my original derivation as follows....
$$=-g^{km}g^{\ell n} \left( \Gamma_{k i \ell} + \Gamma_{\ell i k} \right)$$
$$=-g^{km}g^{\ell n} \partial_i g_{k\ell}$$
...which is basically what you mentioned, just via a much more long-winded process!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, when possible try to avoid raising/lowering the indices of the Christoffel symbols: they do not form a tensor, hence the raising/lowering of their indices is not well defined!

Comment: Oh, hmm. Didn't realize that. Maybe my misplaced indices are just a shorthand contraction of using the metric in places. The first index transforms like a tensor, though, right? Just not the second and third? Or am I wrong on that?

Comment: You're right. You can consistently lower the upper index (it amounts to removing the inverse metric which multiplies the derivatives), but not raise the lower indices (unless of course you choose some specific definition and stick to it).